# Customizing Asp.Net Identity 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to customize Asp.Net Identity 3 classes.

Here is what I did:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
```

and

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
```

I also extended `IdentityUserClaim<int>, IdentityRole<int>, IdentityUserLogin<int> and IdentityUserRole<int>` but I get the following error:

```
The type 'User' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method' IdentityDbContext<TUser>'.There is no implicit reference conversion from 'User' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser'.
```

Comment: What is your goal? What you want to achieve with your custom changes?

Comment: To use int as primary key...

Comment: Take a look at my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how you made your class to inherit `IdentityUser<int>` as generic version of `IdentityUser' has more type parameters. Check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613256%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

So, you will need:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
```

and:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
```

Edit:
For Identity 3.0 things are a bit different, but problem is similar.
According to: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs

`IdentityDbContext<TUser>` is like this:

```
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser> : IdentityDbContext<TUser, IdentityRole, string> where TUser : IdentityUser
{ }
```

Important part is `where TUser : IdentityUser`
Definition of IdenityUser is:

```
public class IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string>
{ ... }
```

And your `User` class inherits `IdentityUser<int>` so it doesn't have implicit conversion to 'IdentityUser' because `int`/`string` difference.

Solution would be to inherit from `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey>` where TUser would be your `User` class, `TRole` would be new Role class that iherits `IdentityRole<int>` and `TKey` is `int`:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int> {...}
public class User : IdentityUser<int> {...}
public class Role : IdentityRole<int> {...}
```

Comment: It does have more parameters but in Identity 2.0, not in Identity 3.0. I already have customized model in Identity 2.0 which is working. trying to do it now in Identity 3 although it is in pre release still...

Comment: I see. I had similar problem few weeks ago and was too eager to answer :)
I edited my answer and added new info. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This should be enough:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{

}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>
{

}

public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can customize the default classes in Identity. I have created a easily used wrapper over Identity Framework and I created my custom class with additional properties. If you wanna take a look, visit [blog](http://www.codingeek.com/dotnet/codenode-identity-an-implementation-of-asp-net-identity/)